# Return the right parent's `get` after a child `post` action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parent-child

I have the same child action placed in several parents actions, let's say there are these two parent views :

```
@model Parent1Model 

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Parent1";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
@Html.Action("Child","MainControler")
```

The second parent :

```
@model Parent2Model

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Parent2";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
@Html.Action("Child","MainControler")
```

All actions are placed in the same controller.

```
public ActionResult parent1() //GET
{
    Parent1Model model = new Parent1Model()
    return View(model );
}
public ActionResult parent2() //GET
{
    Parent2Model model = new Parent2Model()
    return View(model );
}
public ActionResult Child() //GET
{
    ChildModel model = new ChildModel()
    return View(model );
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Child(ChildModel model) //POST
{
    DoThingsWithResult(model)

    // The next line should return the get of the parent action

    return RedirectToParent() // This does not exist...
}
```

Now, how do i tell the child to call his RIGHT parent's `GET`? Being the child of many parents, how can he know which parent called it this time ?

I could not find anything, neither on google nor in the "Questions that may already have your answer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add one more param to determine where it is coming from, 
you can also make this param a string which will be the parent action name itself and pass that param to your `RedirectToAction(param)`

Ex

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Child(string ParentName, ChildModel model) //POST
{
    DoThingsWithResult(model)

    // The next line should return the get of the parent action

    return RedirectToAction(ParentName) // This does not exist...
}
```

in your parent action

```
public ActionResult parent2() //GET
{
    Parent2Model model = new Parent2Model();
    ViewBag.Parent = "parent2";
    return View(model );
}
```

in your view

```
@model Parent2Model

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Parent2";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
@Html.Action("Child","MainControler", new {ParentName= ViewBag.Parent})
```

Do the same for Parent Action 1